# Google Cloud Run service deployment, is it the best direction in my situation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have some experience with Google Cloud Functions (CF). I tried to deploy a CF function recently with a Python app, but it uses an NLP model so the 8GB memory limit is exceeded when the model is triggered. **The function is triggered when a JSON file is uploaded to a bucket**.

So, I plan to try Google Cloud Run but I have no experience with it. Also, I am not completely sure if it is the best course of action.

If it is, what is the best way of implementing provided that the Run service will be triggered by a file uploaded to a bucket? In CF, you can select the triggering event, in Run I didn't see anything like that. I could use some starting points as I couldn't find my case in the GCP documentation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *at least* these two things:

- The legacy one: [Create a GCS notification in PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). Then create a push subscription and add the Cloud Run URL in the HTTP push destination
- A more recent way is to use [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/quickstart-storage) to invoke directly a Cloud Run endpoint from an event (it roughly create the same thing with a PubSub topic and push subscription, but it's fully configured for you)

---

**EDIT 1**

When you use Push notification, you will received a standard PubSub message. The format is described in the documentation for [the attributes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#attributes) and for the [body content](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#payload); keep in mind that the raw content is base64 encoded and you have to decode it to get the [final format](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations)

*I personally have a Cloud Run service that log the contents of any requests to be able to get in the logs all the data that I need to develop. When I have a new message format, I configure the push to that Cloud Run endpoint and I automatically get the format*

For Eventarc, the format will be added to the UI soon (I view that feature in preview, but it's not yet available). The best solution is to log the content to know what you get to know what to do!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, @guillaume blaquiere. I am struggling with how Google Cloud will send the JSON file into my main function. In Cloud Function, I get the JSON file from data part of the (data, context) input parameters. I think it is automatically sent by Google Cloud. What is the counterpart of it in the Cloud Run setting?